# Как можно позволить кому-то запускать мои функции и процедуры, но НЕ просмотривать их исходные коды?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть схема БД с функциями, процедурами и пакетами.

Хочу разрешить некоторым разработчикам доступ к моим таблицам только для чтения, поэтому я создаю для них пользователя с доступом `READ ONLY` к моим таблицам. Хочу предоставить им `EXECUTE` на мои процедуры и функции, но НЕ разрешить просматривать их исходный текст (код).

Когда предоставляю `EXECUTE` на мои функции или процедуры, то они могут просто сделать `DESCRIBE` (в SQL-Developer разработчике или TOAD), или просматривать код из представления `all_source`.

Как запретить им просматривать мои исходные тексты PL/SQL?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How can I allow someone to run my Oracle functions/procedures but not able to view its source codes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65777745) от участника [@angkong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15031065/angkong)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65777745

Answer (score 4):

Поместите все функции и процедуры в пакеты. Дайте права на выполнение этих пакетов другому пользователю.

Имея права на выполнение, другой пользователь может выполнить процедуру из пакета, видеть спецификацию пакета, но не сможет видеть тело пакета, то есть код реализации.

```
create or replace package pack as
    type tab is table of int;
    procedure proc (par tab);
end;
/
create or replace package body pack as
    procedure proc (par tab) is 
    begin null;
    end;
end;
/
grant execute on pack to me;
```

Под другим пользователем:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "ME"
SQL> select name, type, text
  2  from all_source where name='PACK'
  3  order by type, line
  4  /

NAME     TYPE         TEXT
-------- ------------ --------------------------------
PACK     PACKAGE      package pack as
PACK     PACKAGE          type tab is table of int;
PACK     PACKAGE          procedure proc (par tab);
PACK     PACKAGE      end;

SQL>
```